# How to force Word to reload the sources.xml file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2008, citations

I converted some references from my citation management program to words sources.xml file.
The file should be located in the word user data folder. All tutorials say that just overwriting the Sources.xml file will add the new references to my citation list for using them in my document.

If I overwrite the Sources.xml the citation list does not change. Restarting word does also not help. It seems that Word does not read the new files and therefore does not find my new references.

Is there any other way to import my references into word?

I'm working with Mac OS on a PowerPC and Word 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The Sources.xml file you have overwritten may not have been the 'correct' one. (Force an update and check for a change in the modification date). Alternatively, your Word document may not have been looking where Sources.xml is stored. [UWEC](https://www.uwec.edu/help/Word07/bib-srcfile.htm) has a detailed guide that may help.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a thought, but maybe you could repopulate your XML.

If you're comfortable with developer mode, you could write a routine in VBA using code like this:

```
Sub RefreshXML()
    Dim myXMLns as string   'the name of the XML namespace
    Dim myXMLdoc as string  'the fully enumerated filepath to the XML file
    myXML = "the-name-of-the-Custom-XML-part"
    ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Item(myXMLns).Delete
    ' Add a new, empty custom XML part to the document.
    ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add 
    ' Load XML from CustomerData.xml file.
    ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(4).Load (myXMLdoc)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious - why the downvote?